# Speech recognition help for non-english language

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am trying to create a web app using asp.net to support Speech recognition. The catch is that I want to convert Swedish audio to text. I have tried several APIs and frameworks but no luck. I only could get [AT&T](https://developer.att.com/apis/speech/docs#sample-apps) to work, sort of. It only recognizes one word in a six word sentence. I also tried Micosoft.Speech library but couldn't get it to work. can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

```
var engine = null as SpeechRecognitionEngine;

engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));


using (engine)
{
    engine.SetInputToWaveFile("C:\\temp\\samplecall.wav");


    var result = engine.Recognize();

    Console.WriteLine(((result != null) ? new SpeechRecognitionResult(result.Text, result.Alternates.Select(x => x.Text).ToArray()).toString : null));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

any other help regarding the speech recognition would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Please, don't write like this, it's better to write `using(var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("sv-SE"))) { ... }` then your 3 first lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transcribe 8khz audio from calls, desktop speech recognition APIs will not help you, so Microsoft is not your choice.

AT&T should work if you configure it properly. Another alternative would be to build an callcenter acoustic model for [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net), the Swedish database for that is available.

Comment: I tried to get AT&T to work but the  x-language and x-grammar in the request are mandatory, and I'm not sure how to set them. I can't find any good example. Do I have to send the whole Swedish grammar with every recognition request I make?
I didn't look that much into CMUSphinx, because I want the solution be in C#, I'm not sure if there is a reliable C# wrapper for CMUSphinx. Any recommendations?

Comment: Where can you download this Swedish database?

Comment: Thanks. It's Norwegian. But maybe the data can be used for Swedish as well?

Comment: There is Swedish data on the same site

Comment: Seems to NST-SAMPA format? Can it be converted to e.g. IPA or Arpabet?